# Need help finding error in this program, compiles but doesn't computer necessary figure

Tags: java

This program compiles and runs, but doesn't calculate the insurance premium. I have been working on it for days and cannot figure it out. It was running in another version before, but we are required to have the 2 classes now and now it does not calculate the insurance, or it is showing as zero in every answer. We are also required to use the panes for the input.

```
// The Premium class represents an insurance premium cost for an individual policy.


public class Premium
{
  private int a; // to hold customer age
  private int h; // to hold customer height
  private int w; // to hold customer weight
  private String s; // to hold smoking status

  int i; // to hold insurance price

   //setAge set's customer's height 
   public void setAge(int age)
   {
      a = age;
     }

   //setHeight set's customer's height 
   public void setHeight(int height)
   {
      h = height;
     }

  //setWeight set's customer's weight
   public void setWeight(int weight)
   {
      w= weight;
    }

   //setSmoke set's customer's smoking status 
   public void setSmoke(String smoker)
   {
      s = smoker;
     }


   //getHeight method returns customer's height 
   public int getHeight()
   {
      return h;
   }

   //getWeight method returns customer's weight 
   public int getWeight()
   {
      return w;
   }

   //getAge method returns customer's age
   public int getAge()
   {
      return a;
   }

   //getSmoke returns customer's smoking status 
   public String getSmoke()
   {
      return s;
     }


   //constructor
   public Premium(int age, int height, int weight, String smoker)
   {
    age = a;
    height = h;
    weight = w;
    smoker = s;
   }


   //calculate individual insurance price method 
      public static int calculateInsurance(int age, String smoker) 
      {
         //variables
         String smoking = "smoker";
         int insurance;
         final int insuranceBase = 400;

         //create new instance of BMI class
          BMI custBMI = new BMI();

          double bmi= custBMI.calculateBMI();


         //calculate insurance
         if (age > 50){
            insurance = insuranceBase + 100;
            }
            else{
             insurance = insuranceBase;
            }

          if (smoker.equals('Y')){
            insurance += 150;
            }else {
            insurance +=0;
            }

           if (bmi > 40){
            insurance += 100;
            } else {
            insurance +=0;
            }

       return insurance;

       }

   //setInsurance method sets insurance price
    public void setInsurance(int insurance)
    {
      i = insurance;
     }

   //getInsurance method returns insurance price
   public int getInsurance()
   {
      return i;
   }



  public void displayPrice()
  {
   System.out.println("Insurance Premium Cost: " + getInsurance());
  }
}

*************************************
/** BMI class calculates customer's BMI
*/

public class BMI
{
   private int h; //to hold customer's height
   private int w; //to hold customer's weight

   //setWeight set's customer's weight
   public void setWeight(int weight)
   {
      w= weight;
    }
   //set height set's customer's height 
   public void setHeight(int height)
   {
      h = height;
     }

   //getWeight method returns customer's weight 
   public int getWeight()
   {
      return w;
   }

   //getHeight method returns customer's height 
   public int getHeight()
   {
      return h;
   }

   // calculate customer's BMI  
   public double calculateBMI()
      {  
         double bmi; 
         //calculate BMI 
         bmi = (getWeight() * 703)/(getHeight() * getHeight());

         return bmi;
      }


 }
*******************************************

  This program will demonstrate the Premium and BMI classes. This program will prompt users for input, 
  use that input to calculate BMI and their insurance rate.
  Output will be the customer profile: name, age, smoker status, height, weight and insurance premium cost. 
  Program will then ask user if they want to create another profile. 
*/

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //required for dialog boxes

public class Project2_1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
      String submit;

      System.out.println("Welcome! Please fill out the following information to get an insurance premium quote.");
      System.out.println();


     do{
     //get customerInfo method promts user for their information
      String input; // to hold user input
      String fname;
      String lname;
      int age;
      String smoker;
      int height;
      int weight;


      //get customer input
      fname =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your first name: ");
      lname =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your last name: ");
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your age: ");
         age = Integer.parseInt(input);
      //validate input
      while (age < 0 || age > 141)
      { 
         input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input! Age must be 1 through 140. Please enter your age: ");
         age = Integer.parseInt(input);
      }

      smoker = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a smoker? Please enter Y or N: ");
      //validate input
      if (!smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))  
      { 
        System.out.println("");   
         }else if (!smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
         {
         smoker = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input! Are you a smoker? Answer must be Y or N: ");
         } else 
            {
               System.out.println("");
               }
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your height in inches: ");
         height = Integer.parseInt(input);
      //validate input
      while (height < 0 || height > 108)
       { 
         input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input! Height must be between 1 and 108 inches. Please enter your height in inches: ");
         height = Integer.parseInt(input);
      }
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
         weight= Integer.parseInt(input);
      //validate input
      while (weight < 0 || weight > 800)
       { 
         input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input! Weight must be between 1 and 800 pounds. Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
         weight = Integer.parseInt(input);
      }

    //create instance of the Premium class

     Premium customer = new Premium(age, height, weight, smoker);


     //call method to display individual results                 
     displayResults(fname, lname, age, smoker, height, weight);    

     //get data from customer and displays  calculated results
      customer.displayPrice();

     submit =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to submit another profile? Enter Y or N: ");
     //validate input
       if (!submit.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))  
      { 
        System.out.println("");  

         } else if (!smoker.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))

            {  submit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input!Another profile? Answer must be Y or N: ");

            } else {
               System.out.println("");
             }  
      } while (submit.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

  }  

      //method to display customer profile information
     public static void displayResults(String fname, String lname, int age, String smoker, int height, int weight)
      {

           //Output  
           System.out.println(" ");
           System.out.println("First Name:             " + fname); 
           System.out.println("Last Name:              " + lname);  
           System.out.println("Age:                    " + age);
           System.out.println("Smoking Status:         " + smoker);
           System.out.println("Height(in.):            " + height);
           System.out.println("Weight(lbs):            " + weight);
           System.out.println(" ");
   }

 }
```

Comment: This would be best answered by using a debugger to test your program as it runs.

Comment: To start, look at your Premium constructor. You pass in int age, but in the body of the constructor you write age = a when it looks like it should be a = age. Go over your code again, carefully, looking for these type of semantic errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting any compiler errors, then it's a logical error in your code.

Looks to me like the `calculateInsurance` method is never called.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed those now I think, same thing, runs, compiles, but no insurance price.

Comment: //setInsurance method sets insurance price
    public void setInsurance(int insurance)
    {
      calculateInsurance(a, s);
      i = insurance;
     }
     
   //getInsurance method returns insurance price
   public int getInsurance()
   {
      return i;
   }
   


  public void displayPrice()
  {
   System.out.println("Insurance Premium Cost: " + getInsurance());
  }
}

Comment: Well then you still have a logical error that has to do with your customer object. Have you used both customer.calculateInsurance() and customer.displayPrice()?

Comment: Yes, thank you, there seems to be something wrong now in the BMI calculation and that class being used in the premium class, now instead of   a zero figure, I am getting an "arithmetic error"